# How to find a function having following properties?

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Let the function be $f(x)$ such that it is monotonic and continuous function

It has maximum area between $x=0$ and $x=1$

$f'(x)$ = $f(x)(1-f(x))$

$f''(0.5) =0$ thus, gradient is maximum at 0.5.

We are looking for  which is increases linearly with $x$ after  $f(x)>=1$ , decreases linearly with $x$ when  $f(x) <= 0$.

We are looking to make small changes in Sigmoid function to find maxima and minima using Euler–Lagrange equation of the calculus of variations.

Is there a Lagrangian through which we can arrive to sigmoid or is it just some heuristic?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that we can write:

$$y'=y-y^2 \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=y-y^2 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{y-y^2}dy=dx$$

Integrating both sides:

$$\int \frac{1}{y-y^2} dy=\int 1 \  dx $$

The first integral is pretty easy(the second trivial):

$$\int \frac{1}{y-y^2} dy=\int \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{1-y} dy=\ln(y)-\ln(1-y)+c=\ln\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)+c$$

So:

$$\ln\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)=x+c$$

$$\frac{y}{1-y}=e^{x+c}$$
$$y=e^{x+c}-ye^{x+c}$$
$$y=\frac{e^{x+c}}{1+e^{x+c}}$$

That can be rewritten as:

$$y=\frac{e^{x}}{c+e^{x}}  \ \ \ \ c>0$$

Let's impose the condition $$f''(\frac 12)=0$$:

$$y''=\frac{c e^x (c-e^x)}{(c+e^x)^3}$$

$$\frac{c e^{\frac 12} (c-e^{\frac 12})}{(c+e^{\frac 12})^3}=0$$

$$c=0 \vee c=\sqrt{e} $$

Since $c>0$ the only solution is the second one:

$$y=\frac{e^x}{e^x+\sqrt{e}}$$

:)